# openjdk@8 java is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way in macOS Monterey

Tags: java, maven, java-8, macos-monterey

I'm getting this error when running some mvn test on my Java application in macOS Monterey

```
WARNING: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@8/1.8.0+322/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: this seems like a warning and not like an error. What are you trying to do? Is there code necessary for explaining? Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Refer to this [Github issue](https://github.com/cl-plus-ssl/cl-plus-ssl/issues/114) and please say if it answers your question.

Comment: @dan1st it is a warning but when I run the tests in IntelliJ, it's stopping them from running

Comment: @JettoMartínez Thank you, i followed the steps here https://github.com/cl-plus-ssl/cl-plus-ssl/issues/114#issuecomment-988295059 That solved the issue!

Comment: Here's another related link here https://issueantenna.com/repo/juxt/site but the difference is it didn't link both libcrypto and libssl to /usr/local/lib/

Answer (score 0):

The following solved the issue for me:

1. Install the latest version of openssl

```
brew install openssl
```

2. Make `libcrypto.dylib` and `libssl.dylib` visible when you execute java

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.3/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib

ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.3/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib
```